# Mvc Telerik Window does not post values of partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

Good day,

I have the following scenario:
I have a Razor view with a "@using(Html.BeginForm(....))" statement at the top of the page. Inside the using statement I have a few textboxes, whose values get populated by the user, and a button.

At the click of that button, a telerik modal window (displaying a partial view of the same model as the initial view) pops up so that the user can populate some more fields. Inside the modal window there is a button that must submit the entire form, which it does, however after I debug my action, I notice that the model is missing the values which were entered in the popup (partial view).

My code for the telerik window resides inside the using statement and looks as follows:

```
            Html.Telerik().Window()
                .Name("AddEditScaleWindow")
                .Title("Save Scale")
                .Content(@<text>@Html.Partial("AddUpdateFeeScale")</text>)
                .Buttons(e => e.Close())
                .Height(250)
                .Width(350)
                .Modal(true)
                .Draggable(true)
                .Visible(false)
                .Render();
```

I tried different methods of getting the window to post its values but to no avail.

If I view source, I can see that the window (partial view) is inside the form. If I do a network trace I can see that the values being posted are all values that were entered on the view, but none from the partial view.

Does anyone have any idea why the values inside the window don't get posted?

Thank you in advance.

Matei

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check this because I am guessing, but many dialog renderers create their dom elements below document and outside of your Form element. If that is the case with Telerik, you will need to do a bit of work on the client to copy the values from the dialog back to your other form.

Comment: When I view source, I can definitely see that the generated html of the window (including the controls of the partial view) is within my form tags. I still haven't found a solution, and contemplating abandoning the control altogether :(

Comment: Is your form element encompassing your inputs and the submit button? Sometimes you will find that the form element is closed immediately and so there are no inputs inside it.

Comment: It's odd because I can remember using Telerik dialogs as part of my form without any issues.